# infinite scroll of primereact multiselect

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll, multi-select, primereact

On dropdown click call API with first 10 item and display in the dropdown list. after then if user scroll down of the dropdown list then again call api with other 10 item. also same thing filter if user search any things then start from 1 page. in sort i need to implement infinite scroll of primereact multiselect

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { MultiSelect } from "primereact/multiselect";
import { VirtualScroller } from "primereact/virtualscroller"; // Import VirtualScroller

export default function FilterDemo() {
  const [selectedCities, setSelectedCities] = useState([]);
  const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
  const pageSize = 10;
  const endReachedThreshold = 200; // Adjust this value based on your UI

  const containerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCities = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_page=${pageSize}&_limit=10`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setCities((prevCities) => [...prevCities, ...data]); // Append fetched data to cities
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching cities:", error);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };

    fetchCities();
  }, [pageNumber]); // Fetch cities when page number changes

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = containerRef.current;
    if (scrollHeight - scrollTop <= clientHeight + endReachedThreshold) {
      setPageNumber((prevPageNumber) => prevPageNumber + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <MultiSelect
      value={selectedCities}
      onChange={(e) => setSelectedCities(e.value)}
      options={cities}
      optionLabel="name"
      filter
      onScroll={handleScroll}
      placeholder="Select Cities"
      maxSelectedLabels={3}
      className="w-full md:w-20rem"
    ></MultiSelect>
  );
}
```